# Certbot DNS/apache wildcard not working for double sub-domain?

Tags: apache, certbot, certbot-dns-plugin

I've successfully set-up an SSL-certificate through the certbot with DNS-plugin. This works great and I have issued a certificate for example.com and *.example.com:

`certbot certificates` output:

```
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Found the following certs:
  Certificate Name: example.com
    Domains: example.com *.example.com
    Expiry Date: 2022-02-28 11:09:56+00:00 (VALID: 89 days)
    Certificate Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
    Private Key Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

So far so good, all domains seem to be secured correctly:

```
example.com = OK
test.example.com = OK
```

However, the issue starts for the domain `test1.test.example.com`. The browser keeps complaining about the fact that the domain is not secured..! I've already re-issued the SSL-certificate. This succeeds, but still the domain is marked as insecure.

Important to note, if I modify the `Apache` config for the domain to not redirect `http (insecure)` traffic to `https (secure)` traffic, I can access the site. This validates my apache set-up, which in fact is only 1 config file, allowing:

```
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias *.example.com
```

***EDIT***: Perhaps this helps. Safari tells me that the name of the certificate `example.com` does not match the input? Firefox returns `SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN`. So, I tried to update the domain to also allow `*.*.example.com`, but that's not allowed by certbot as it returns: `Cannot issue for '*.*.example.com': Domain name has more than one wildcard`

***EDIT 2***: The DNS-plugin generated a json-file that contains the auth-information to validate the domains. This file contains an entry `fulldomain` and `subdomain`, but the issue is with a `two level 'sub-sub' domain`? Perhaps this is the issue? How can I fix this, as the certbot plugin does not allow multi wildcard domains?

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out, it's not allowed to use a wildcard character before the first dot in the domain-name (at least not with the DNS-plugin I use).

Therefore, I successfully got it working adding the domain like: -d *.test.example.com

After issuing and overwriting the old certificate with the new one, this worked perfectly as expected.

```
example.com = OK
test.example.com = OK
test1.test.example.com = OK
```